# rest service not working on jboss 6.0 eap

Tags: spring, rest, jboss

We have written a service controller for providing rest services in spring which is like---

```
@Controller
public class ServicesController {
    //first service
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/emailDomainValidate", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = { jsonContentType })
    public List<String> emailDomailValidate(@RequestBody EmailDomainValidateVO emailDomainValidate) {
        List<String> errorCodes = getEmailDomainValidationService().emailDomainValidation(
        emailDomainValidate);
    }

    //second service
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/changePassword", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = { jsonContentType })
    public List<String> changePassword(@RequestBody ChangePasswordVO changePasswordVO) {
        List<String> passwords = getChangePasswordFacade().changePassword(changePasswordVO);

    }

}
```

In web.xml we have provided

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

when we are accessing one of the service by making a rest call----http://"url":8080/service/emailDomainValidate --- this is working

but when we are accessing the other service 
http://"url":8080/service/changePassword--- this is not working and is giving us 400 http error code

The steps we have executed so far are ----

1. deleting the temp directory for the server.
2. redeployment
3. change the input class vo for the service which is not working----ChangePasswordVO

please let me why this is still not working when every other service provided is working

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a mapping to the controller then add mapping to your methods.  This is working for me at least:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping('/rest')
public class ServicesController {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ExampleRestController.class);

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/emailDomainValidate", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = { jsonContentType })
    public List<String> emailDomailValidate(@RequestBody EmailDomainValidateVO emailDomainValidate) {
        if(log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug('emailDomainValidate hit');
        List<String> errorCodes = getEmailDomainValidationService().emailDomainValidation(emailDomainValidate);
    }

    //second service
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/changePassword", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = { jsonContentType })
    public List<String> changePassword(@RequestBody ChangePasswordVO changePasswordVO) {
        if(log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug('change password hit');

        List<String> passwords = getChangePasswordFacade().changePassword(changePasswordVO);
    }

}
```

You then would post to:

```
http://localhost:8080/service/rest/emailDomainValidate
http://localhost:8080/service/rest/changePassword
```

Comment: thanks jyore for answering, rest of the services mentioned are working so don't think it has to be issue with the mapping provided

Comment: This problem is coming up only with Jboss clustered environment when been executed on standalone it works perfectly fine